# Logging stop rolling to new files

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j

Current spring application takes `slf4j`, `log4j` and `slf4j-log4j12` as logging utility.

Problems are,

(1) Each time when the log file is opened on by external tool(wordpad or ultraedit), then the file stopped to roll over. It is very annoying as the file may grow like 10 gigabytes.

(2) `MaxFileSize` is set to 10Mb, but each time the log file rolling to 20Mb.

here is the config

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, ROL
log4j.appender.ROL=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ROL.Encoding=Unicode
log4j.appender.ROL.File=D:\\IamdWatchingYou.log
log4j.appender.ROL.MaxFileSize=10000KB
log4j.appender.ROL.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.ROL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ROL.layout.ConversionPattern=%d -- %p -- %c -- %m%n
```

And this issue happens in general all major app servers(Tomcat, websphere and sometimes, Jboss).

The question is, what is the root cause(compatibility or configuration). If choose other logging implementations(Logback or JDK logging), is it going to fix the issue? I simply just wish to stop making huge log files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour of the rollover logic, you can see it in the log4j class `RollingFileAppender`.

The rollover logic tries to rename the current log file to a name containing a timestamp, and if it does not manage to due for example the fact that the file is opened by another application, the rollover logic will fail silently and not do any change (no warning or errors are logged).

This means logging will be continued to be made in the same file, until the next time that the rollover logic is executed successfully.

Comment: thanks. Can I take your statement as what is happening is normal? Then how to view a log file without messing up log4j rolling process? If it is windows system, plenty editors will place a lock on the log file and confuse Log4J, how to prevent this happening?

Comment: that is right, its normal behaviour. in windows, use Notepad++ and you will not have the problem. IT will ask you to reload the file from time to time but it will not lock it, see http://superuser.com/questions/21071/editor-that-does-not-lock-an-open-file

Comment: Interesting. I use notepad++ in windows and this issue occurs. May be cause of this issue also related to item(2) in the question: even `MaxFileSize` is set to 10Mb, the log file still roll over to 20Mb, if I don't open any of the log files in notepad++. It seems the configuration is overridden by default setting, where I don't really know..

Comment: UltraEdit does not lock a file if the usage of temporary files is enabled which is by default and the configuration setting to always lock a file is also not used as by default. It is even possible to delete a file while viewing/editing it in UltraEdit. UltraEdit has even a special polling feature to view a log file while it is growing.

Comment: What encoding is used for the log file, ANSI or Unicode (UTF-16)? A MaxFileSize of 10 MB could mean 10.485.760 characters which is with ASCII/ANSI encoding also 10.485.760 bytes, but with UTF-16 encoding 20.971.520 bytes (+ 2 more bytes if BOM also written to log file). Unicode (UTF-16 LE?) is used according to configuration.